# Excel MaxIF function fails but runs as sub

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to write a MaxIf user defined function. The code runs perfectly as a sub but the Do Loop fails as a function with no error. I stepped through it as a function but that revealed no clue.

```
Public Function udfMaxIf(criteria As Range, criteria_range As Range, max_range As Range)

Dim dblValues() As String
Dim lngMax As Long
Dim lngX As Long, intLastRow As Integer
Dim strSearch As String
Dim rngCriteria As Range, strFirst As String, strLast As String

strSearch = criteria.Value
'# setting after = to last row in range forces the Find to start from, and including, the first line of the range. Else it starts from top
'# row but doesn't search it until last.
With criteria_range
    intLastRow = .Rows.Count
    Set rngCriteria = .Find(strSearch, after:=criteria_range.Cells(intLastRow, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
End With

If Not rngCriteria Is Nothing Then
    '# set the value of the first appearance of rngCriteria to array(0)
    ReDim dblValues(0)
    strFirst = rngCriteria.Address
    strLast = criteria_range.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Address
    dblValues(0) = Cells(rngCriteria.Row, max_range.Column).Value
    '# add subsequent values to the array but break when it reaches last row. If this was only value it would have been picked up above.
    Do Until rngCriteria.Address = strLast
        Set rngCriteria = criteria_range.FindNext(rngCriteria)
        ReDim Preserve dblValues(UBound(dblValues) + 1)
        dblValues(UBound(dblValues)) = Cells(rngCriteria.Row, max_range.Column).Value
    Loop
End If

On Error GoTo UBound_handler:
    lngMax = dblValues(0)
    For lngX = 0 To UBound(dblValues)
        If dblValues(lngX) > lngMax Then
            lngMax = dblValues(lngX)
        End If
    Next lngX
On Error Resume Next
udfMaxIf = lngMax
Exit Function
UBound_handler:
If Err.Number = 9 Then
    MsgBox "Criteria not found in criteria range", vbInformation
Else:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End If
Exit Function
End Function
```

The methodology could be improved but I'm more concerned with figuring out why it won't work as a function. Thanks.

Comment: Does this need to a be a UDF?  MaxIf can be written like this (and needs to be entered as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter): `=MAX(IF(A1:A10="Criteria",B1:B10))`

Comment: No it doesn't and now I know other ways of doing it I probably will. Now I'm just curious why it doesn't work.

Comment: I am finding that the findnext line is not finding any next and rngCriteria comes up as nothing, so you get the error when trying to find the row of range that is nothing.

Comment: When the Do loop fails (with no error) what line is the last line/what line would be next line to execute if the failure didn't occur?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `FindNext`. when I make some trivial example that will exit the function abruptly and return a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: for some reason rngCriteria sets itself to Nothing thus causing the FindNext to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer to iterate over arrays as I find that is more reliable and faster than other methods.  Something like this would work for you as a MaxIf UDF:

```
Public Function MaxIf(ByVal rCriteria As Range, ByVal sCriteria As String, ByVal rMax As Range) As Variant

    Dim aCrit As Variant
    Dim aValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim dMax As Double

    aCrit = rCriteria.Value
    aValues = rMax.Value
    If rCriteria.Rows.Count & "," & rCriteria.Columns.Count <> rMax.Rows.Count & "," & rMax.Columns.Count Then
        MaxIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not IsArray(aCrit) Then
        If LCase(aCrit) Like LCase(sCriteria) Then MaxIf = aValues Else MaxIf = 0
    Else
        dMax = -10 ^ 308
        For i = 1 To UBound(aCrit, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(aCrit, 2)
                If LCase(aCrit(i, j)) Like LCase(sCriteria) Then
                    If IsNumeric(aValues(i, j)) Then
                        If aValues(i, j) > dMax Then dMax = aValues(i, j)
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        If dMax > -10 ^ 308 Then MaxIf = dMax Else MaxIf = 0
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dblValues(0) = Cells(rngCriteria.Row, max_range.Column).Value
```

Lines like this may be problematic since you've not scoped `Cells()` to a specific worksheet, so it's going to default to whatever is the Activesheet (unless you have this code in a sheet module)

Comment: Ah, I kind of assumed that it would take that from the range info supplied.

Comment: That's a common assumption - lots of questions here have that as the core of the issue

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll rework it and see what I come up with. Out of curiosity though, why does it work when run as a sub? I still haven't declared or scoped Cells...

Comment: I'm not saying for sure that this is *the* problem, but it is *a* problem   ;-)

Comment: now that I think about it,  when I ran it as a sub, I declared the sheet name.

Answer (score 1):

Example Data beginning in Cell A1, and a value of "A" in cell G2, calling UDF as `=foo(G2, A1:D6)`

```
A   B   C   D
E   F   G   H
I   J   A   B
C   D   E   F
G   H   I   J
A   B   C   D
```

Here is a trivial example which you can run as either a function or a sub.

```
Public Function foo(criteria As Range, criteria_range As Range)

Dim rngCriteria As Range
Dim intLastRow As Long
Dim strSearch$, strFirst$, strLast$
Dim ret
strSearch = criteria.Value
With criteria_range
    intLastRow = .Rows.Count
    Set rngCriteria = .Find(strSearch, after:=criteria_range.Cells(intLastRow, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, searchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
End With
If Not rngCriteria Is Nothing Then

strFirst = rngCriteria.Address
strLast = criteria_range.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, searchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Address

Do Until rngCriteria.Address = strLast
    Set rngCriteria = criteria_range.FindNext(rngCriteria)
Loop
End If
ret = rngCriteria.Address
foo = ret  '// Comment this line if calling as Sub
Debug.Print ret
End Function
```

Stepping through the code, you'll observe the `Do` loop fails silently on the second pass when run as a UDF from the worksheet, but it will execute without error when called as a `Sub` from Immediate pain in VBE.

There are some limitations to UDFs which are (not very well) explained at this KB article:

```
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787
```

A quick google [search suggests that `Find`](http://www.excel-it.com/excel_udf.html) is one of the forbidden methods, although that does not seem to be the case. The problem as you & I have both observed is that `FindNext` returns nothing and your `Do` loop relies on a non-`Nothing` to query the `Address` property. If `FindNext` was forbidden, I would expect an error/silent failure on that expression, so **perhaps this is a bug.**

Since `Find` is not causing the error, it may be possible to re-work the UDF to use only the `Find` method in a loop, instead of the `FindNext` method.

```
Public Function newfoo(criteria As Range, criteria_range As Range)
Dim rngCriteria As Range
Dim intLastRow As Long
Dim strSearch$, strFirst$, strLast$
Dim ret
strSearch = criteria.Value

With criteria_range
    intLastRow = .Rows.Count
    Set rngCriteria = .Find(strSearch, After:=criteria_range.Cells(intLastRow, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, searchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
End With
If Not rngCriteria Is Nothing Then
    ret = rngCriteria.Address
    strFirst = rngCriteria.Address
    strLast = criteria_range.Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, searchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Address
    Do
        Set rngCriteria = criteria_range.Find(strSearch, After:=rngCriteria, LookIn:=xlValues, searchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rngCriteria Is Nothing Then
            ret = ret & "|" & rngCriteria.Address
            If rngCriteria.Address = strLast Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End If
Debug.Print ret
foo = ret
End Function
```

Or you may be able to reconfigure your `FindNext` arguments. (**untested**)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the ideas and suggestions. I had no idea before that UDFs worked in a different manner to regular subs.

Ultimately I went @tigeravatar array formula that I extended to a multi MAXIF with help from the following:
[MaxIF with multi-criteria](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/11/19/using-max-if-with-multiple-criteria/)

Comment: It would be preferable to give @tigeravatar the "Acceptance" on this answer. Your "answer" here merely indicates that *his* answer is the right one, and it seems wrong of you to mark your own answer as accepted, in this case.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to go about that as the answer I used was in a comment. I marked my answer correct thinking this would stop it showing unanswered rather than trying to give myself credit which wasn't my intention.